# Text does not display on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am having an issue where my ViewPager text does not display when I start up my application. However, the texts do end up showing when I swipe the tab. I am not sure what the problem is and I would like the text to appear as soon as my application starts. Any help would be appreciated! thanks.

Countries Activity(**MAIN ACTIVITY**)

```
package myapps.countryapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import static myapps.countryapp.R.id.pager;

public class CountriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_countries);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final  int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    //Create tab tiles.
    private String tabTiles[]  = new String[] {"Countries", "Map"};
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            Fragment fragmentList = new Countries();
            return fragmentList;
        }else {
            Countries fragmentList = new Countries();
            return fragmentList;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTiles[position];
    }
  }

}//end of class
```

Countries.java(fragment file)

```
package myapps.countryapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Countries extends Fragment {


public Countries() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countries, container, false);
    return view;
}

}
```

activity_countries(**MAIN XML FILE**)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="myapps.countryapp.CountriesActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id = "@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "40dp"
    android:paddingTop = "4dp"
    android:paddingBottom = "10dp"
    android:layout_gravity = "top"
    android:id = "@+id/pagerStrip">

</android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

fragment_countries.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="myapps.countryapp.Countries">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


 <ListView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/MyListView">
  </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What text are you talking about ? The tabs title ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text in PagerTabStrip not displayed upon 1st view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168726/text-in-pagertabstrip-not-displayed-upon-1st-view)

Comment: @Krishnan I am uncertain on how I can downgrade some of my libraries could you provide me some more information on how to go about this? it would be appreciated.

Comment: @GoonCrafter You can always check Android Developers official website for any such doubts.

[Adding Support Libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my example of activity, viewpager and fragment:

activity:

```
public class KataloziSlike extends AppCompatActivity {


    private AdapterCustomPage mAdapterCustomPage;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TextView tv, brojStranica;
    private ImageButton settings, share, locirajMe, back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_katalozi_slike);

        if (Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() == 1) {
            Message.message(KataloziSlike.this, "Katalog ima samo jednu stranu");
        }
        brojStranica = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBrojStranicaKataloga);
        brojStranica.setText(String.valueOf(1) + "/" + String.valueOf(Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() + 1));

        mAdapterCustomPage = new AdapterCustomPage(getFragmentManager(), this);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pagerZaSlikeKataloga);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapterCustomPage);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);


        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if (Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() != 1) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        Message.message(KataloziSlike.this, "Na prvoj stranici kataloga ste");
                    } else if (position == Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() - 1) {
                        Message.message(KataloziSlike.this, "Na poslednjoj stranici kataloga ste");
                    }
                }

                if (position <= Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() - 1) {
                    YourFragmentInterface fragment = (YourFragmentInterface) mAdapterCustomPage.instantiateItem(mViewPager, position);
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        fragment.fragmentBecameVisible();
                    }
                }

                brojStranica.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size() + 1));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
}
}
```

adapter:

```
public class AdapterCustomPage extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    protected Context mContext;
    int maxBrojStrana = Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().size();
    int pozicija;
    private ArrayList<Katalozi> mKatalozi;

    public AdapterCustomPage(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }




    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // Create fragment object
        if (position == maxBrojStrana) {
            Fragment fragment = new ImageFragmentMapKatalozi();
            return fragment;
        } else {
            Fragment fragment = new ImageFragmentKatalozi();
            fragment.onPause();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            Log.i("Poizicija", String.valueOf(position));
            String url = Static.katalozi.getSlikeKataloga().get(position);
            args.putString("url", url);

            fragment.setArguments(args);


            String link = Static.katalozi.getUrl();
            args.putString("linkKataloga", link);




            return fragment;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        pozicija = super.getItemPosition(object);
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return maxBrojStrana + 1;
    }

}
```

and fragment:

```
public class ImageFragmentKatalozi extends Fragment implements KataloziSlike.YourFragmentInterface {


    private PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bundle args;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_katalozi_slike, container, false);

        args = getArguments();
        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAdapterZaListanjeKataloga);


        Callback imageLoadedCallback = new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (mAttacher != null) {
                    mAttacher.update();
                } else {
                    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(args.getString("url")).placeholder(R.drawable.load).error(R.drawable.error).into(imageView, imageLoadedCallback);
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.zaProveru);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "sadsadasd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }


    @Override
    public void fragmentBecameVisible() {
        mAttacher.update();
    }
}
```

What is problem with yours is that it isnt instatiated when first fragment is made, only when you swipe(on fragment change) then its showing. Reffer to my example

Comment: Hello there, I have tried this to my code and it appears I still have the same problem here are some of the changes I have made to my code: myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

I have also added a getItemPosition method to my adapter: 
    @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            a = super.getItemPosition(object);
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }
Still nothing.

Comment: in activity public void onPageSelected(int position)  do this:
if(position == 0){
set text to  your textview here
}

Comment: I am not using a text view in my fragment. I am mainly following the tutorial here: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpagertabstrip-fragments-tutorial/